# Regular expression to match code blocks multiple times

Tags: regex

I want to match a block of code *multiple* times in a file but can't work out the regular expression to do this. An example of the code block is:

```
//@debug
...
// code in here
...
//@end-debug (possibly more comments here on same line)
```

Each code block I'm trying to match will start with `//@debug` and stop at the end of the line containing `//@end-debug`

I have this at the moment:

```
/(\/{2}\@debug)(.|\s)*(\/{2}\@end-debug).*/
```

But this matches one big block from the first `//@debug` all the way to end of the line of the very last `//@end-debug` in the file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically your regular expression is greedy.  This means the wildcard operators grab as much as they possibly can with the results you've seen.  Just change it to non-greedy where appropriate.  In your case use:

/(/{2}\@debug)(.|\s)*?(/{2}\@end-debug).*/

Comment: I'll vote this up, if you indent the code block, so it will be highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to use that `(.|\s)` hack, either, but the syntax for doing it the correct way depends on the language or tool you're using.  In Perl or Javascript, you could do this:

```
/\/\/@debug.*?^\/\/@end-debug[^\r\n]*/sg
```

The `/s` modifier lets the dot match carriage-returns and linefeeds, resulting in a regex that's both easier to read and more efficient.  It also means I had to change the second `.*` to `[^\r\n]*`, but it's worth it.  The `/g` modifier is what lets the regex match multiple times (i.e., "globally").

Answer (score 0):

what language?  python regular expressions (i guess they're == to perl5 regexps) have the concept of 'greedy' vs 'non-greedy' regexps, you can control it through a flag somewhere.

search for "greedy vs non-greedy" on [this page](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html), also [this page](http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/regular_expressions.html) might be better

> Non-greedy quantifiers have the same
>   syntax as regular greedy ones, except
>   with the quantifier followed by a
>   question-mark. For example, a
>   non-greedy pattern might look like:
>   "/A[A-Z]*?B/". In English, this means
>   "match an A, followed by only as many
>   capital letters as are needed to find
>   a B."