# Finding changes to a block of text with mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have a text file that I'd like to track changes with.  It's a file that stores values (as well as strings and arrays) and has the following format for its entries:

```
NAME: some_name
  UNIT: some_unit
  ...
  VALUE: 10
  ...
END
```

I can setup a repsoitory and track changes on this file to see when `VALUE`s change, BUT how can I understand the change history of an entry like `some_name`?  The value changing shows up but since the line with `NAME: some_name` doesn't change I'm not seeing it in search results.  So as of now I don't see how I can see when the last time `some_name` changed or how many times it has changed, etc.

I think this would be similar to understanding the change history of a function, where the user would like to understand the history of the entire function between various revisions.

As of now I'm working with TortoiseHg on a preliminary setup so I'm open to switching tools at this point, I'm also completely new to version-control.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22522480/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+history+%22line+range%22

Comment: Thx!  Entries will come and go so the lines where the block is found will change.  BUT, those search results have something that looks promising... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781405/git-how-do-i-view-the-change-history-of-a-method-function/33953022?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C75.5992#33953022 just need to figure out if I can make a custom function and if mercurial has something similar.

Comment: Why the `git` tag?

Comment: I was open to switching tools if someone knew how to do this in git... I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mercurial the `hg grep` command accepts python regular expressions.

> grep
>
> search revision history for a pattern in specified files:
>
> hg grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]... Search revision history for a
> regular expression in the specified files or the entire project.

So `hg grep --diff "(\bsome_name\b)(.|\s)*?(\bEND\b)"` will match the text from `some_name` to `END` and will return the changes that happened within this chunk of text.  Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/xVq79U/1) and adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348256/regular-expression-to-match-code-blocks-multiple-times).

Also, the same can be accomplished in TortoiseHg using View>Search and putting the regex `(\bsome_name\b)(.|\s)*?(\bEND\b)` in the Search field (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10994314/11305111)).